# Problem with UpdateInterval

Tags: dynamic

I want to monitor current results with `Dynamic`

```
ls = {}; k = 1;

Dynamic[
 Refresh[
   AppendTo[ls, k++];
   Last@ls
, UpdateInterval -> 10]]
```

For some reason output updates instantaneously and not every 10 seconds

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you edit `ls`, all dynamics that depend on `ls` will update instantly, this will cause `ls` to be edited which will update the dynamic which edits `ls`.... etc.

The way to avoid this is to specify that there should be no tracked symbols:

```
Dynamic[Refresh[AppendTo[ls, k++];
 Last@ls, UpdateInterval -> 10], TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

Answer (score 9):

> **TrackedSymbols**
>   is an option to Refresh, Manipulate, and related functions that specifies which symbols should trigger updates when their values are changed.

```
Dynamic[Refresh[AppendTo[ls, k++]; Last@ls, TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

Answer (score 7):

`UpdateInterval` gives an upper bound to the dynamic updates. It doesn't turn off the automatic updating whenever a symbol that is being tracked gets updated.

Your code has `AppendTo[ls, sth]`. Imagine that as an equivalent of `var=Append[ls, sth]; ls=var;` where `var` is just a dummy to show that first Mathematica builds the list and then it assigns it to `ls`.

In `var=Append[ls, sth]`, `ls` gets tracked. Then, `ls` gets changed with `ls=var`, triggering a self-update.

One possible solution is to make your dynamic NOT track changes in `ls`, as the other solutions suggested.

```
Dynamic[Refresh[AppendTo[ls, k++]; Last@ls, None], UpdateInterval -> 2]
```