# Why isn't Refresh working as expected?

Tags: dynamic

This seems to me to be a very easy question, but I can't seem to figure it out. Instead of updating every 1 second, it auto-updates as quickly as possible.

```
Clear[t];
t = 1; Dynamic[Refresh[t++, UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {t}]]
```

I've checked the documentation to no avail. Could someone explain this behaviour an propose a fix?

Comment: From the docs: "UpdateInterval->t specifies that updating should, if possible, be done *at least* every t seconds." You could use a scheduled task to update a symbol, and then display the symbol with `Dynamic`.

Comment: @mfvonh I have edited the question to clarify my problem.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9766/5478)

Comment: @Kuba That seems like a duplicate.  Do you not think so?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so but no 100% sure. Sure enought to cast a close-vote though :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sometimes stuff is hard to find in the docs but in this case your answer is basically there as an explicit example (under Scope). So I'd mark it a duplicate (of the docs).

Comment: @Mike I have no problem with this being closed, but I contend that this is not "easily found in the documentation" because the docs (v10) give no explanation for `TrackedSymbols -> {}` there.  I realize it is teaching by example but at the same time sometimes it takes a description for the "aha!" moment.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard agree that the documentation is very poor. It leaves it up to user to figure it out rather than explain what is happening in examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a Symbol is "tracked" it means that when its value changes the Dynamic expression is refreshed, therefore your input updates as fast as possible because every refresh changes the value of `t` which causes a refresh which... you get the picture.

Compare:

```
Clear[t];

t = 1; Dynamic[Refresh[t++, UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols -> {}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Refresh only sets a limit on how long expression can go without being updated. To keep `t` form being updated more often add a pause.

```
t = 1; Dynamic[Refresh[Pause[1]; t++, UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {t}]]
```

or do what Mr.Wizard indicated, which is better.

But this sort of thing is best done by higher level constructs such as `Clock` or `Trigger`. For example:

```
status[t_, t1_] := Row[{t, " > ", threshold, " is ", t > t1}]

Dynamic[With[{dt = 1, tmax = 10, threshold = 4}, 
  t = Clock[{0, tmax, dt}, tmax, 1]; status[t, threshold]]]
```

The above will run for 10 seconds and will update once a second showing whether or not the value of `t` has passed `t = 4`.

`Trigger` gives more control. The following does what the previous example does, but allows the process to be paused and restarted further, the process can be repeated without re-evaluating the code.

```
With[{dt = 1, tmax = 10, threshold = 4},
  Column[{
    Dynamic @ status[t, threshold],
    Trigger[Dynamic@t, {0, tmax, dt}, dt, 
      AppearanceElements -> {"PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton"}]}]]
```