# Dynamically update a graphic object in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I was trying to simulate a bouncing ball (with no gravity) in a unit box and I managed to come up with a solution:

```
pred[x_] := 1 - UnitStep[x] + UnitStep[x - 1];
DynamicModule[{pos = {0.1, 0.5}, vel = {0.05, 0}, dt = 1}, 
 Graphics[{{White, EdgeForm[Directive[Black, Thick]], 
Rectangle[{-0.2, -0.2}, {1.2, 1.2}]}, 
Circle[Dynamic[
 Refresh[(vel = (pred[pos]*2 {-1, -1}*vel + vel); 
   pos = pos + vel*dt), UpdateInterval -> 1]], 0.02]}]]
```

But there is one problem: the graphic object does not update as frequently as required (once per second), instead it seems to update about 10+ times per second. However, if I changed the motion of the ball to a simpler sinusoidal motion, the graphic object seems to update at a desired frequency:

```
DynamicModule[{}, 
 Graphics[{{White, EdgeForm[Directive[Black, Thick]], 
   Rectangle[{-0.2, -0.2}, {1.2, 1.2}]}, 
   Circle[Dynamic[Refresh[pos={0.5Sin[Clock[Infinity]]+0.5,0.5},UpdateInterval->2]],0.02]}]]
```

So my questions are

1) Why `UpdateInterval` in the first case does not work properly, and

2) Is there any other way to dynamically update the positions of some points in a graphic object if the trajectory of these points cannot be pre-calculated (e.g. with collision involved) or represented as a function of time?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ad 1) You need `TrackedSymbols:>{}`: [Problem with UpdateInterval](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9766/5478) Ad 2) [38927](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38927/5478)

Comment: @Kuba That answers my questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Kuba One more question, when running your code in question 38927, the kernel is always running so that I cannot do any other calculations. But with my code, after executing the kernel is not in the running status (so that I can perform other calculations in the same notebook session) and the graphic object keeps updating. So why a graphic object can keep updating itself with kernel unoccupied?

Comment: The difference is that `go[]` command is just a loop sent with Shift+Enter. Your loop is whole in `Dynamic`. `Dynamic` communicates with Kernel with *preemptive link* and standard evaluation is done by *main link*. The latter is queued (my case), the former isn't (yours). At the end you can set my code so it uses preemptive link only. Take a look at [Synchronous versus Asynchronous Dynamic Evaluations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) in AdvancedDynamicFunctionality tutorial but IntroductionToDynamic is a must too if you want to feel the subject

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you for that.