# Dynamic plot with synchronization of real time

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I want to do a dynamic plot with synchronization of real time, that is, I have a function, f[t], that is a function of time (seconds), so I want to see the curve changing not so fast or not so slow, just in real time (seconds).

I tried this:

```
data = {};
t = 0;
freq = .5 Pi;
f[t] := Sin[freq t] + Sin[1.5 freq t];
Dynamic[
    current=f[t];
    AppendTo[data,current];
    t = t + .05;
    ListPlot[data, PlotRange->{{t-200, t}, {-5, 5}}, ImageSize->Medium],
    UpdateInterval->0]
```

Issues:

1. When I plot, the time is not synchronized, that is, it is too fast or too slow. How do I do it?
2. As time goes on, the plot speed get slower. data vector is too big???
3. How do I stop the "shacking" of the plot along time?

Comment: Is `UpdateInterval->1,  TrackedSymbols:>{}` an answer? [9766](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9766/5478)

Comment: Do you really need near real time data (e.g. constantly polling some sensor data/ querying computable data) or do you just want to visualise some basic function? If your case is the latter have a look at [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html)

Comment: Concerning your second question about performance: A good read might be an [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351) from Leonid Shifrin concerning performance in Mathematica. Constructing lists in a Matlab-esque fashion like you do with `AppendTo` has **terrible** performance in Mathematica.

Comment: @Kuba I looked at updateInterval, but was not sure if it is more "strict" on getting timing exactly as needed than scheduled task. It says `if possible, be done at least every t seconds`. This whole subject of "real time" and Mathematica dynamics is very tricky.

Comment: My goal is to read data from an Arduino connected using USB. The data change with time, for example, temperature (voltage) along time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = {};   
freq = .5 Pi;
f[t_] := Sin[freq t] + Sin[1.5 freq t];
t = 0;
Grid[{{
   Row[{"t=", Dynamic@t}]},
  {Dynamic[
    ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{t - 200, t}, {-5, 5}}, ImageSize -> Medium],
     TrackedSymbols :> {t}]}
  }] 

RunScheduledTask[{t += .5; current = f[t]; AppendTo[data, current]}, {.5, 100}];
```

Then

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
```

See [RunScheduledTask](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunScheduledTask.html)

ps. I would not use append as you are doing. But this is what you had.

Comment: What is the best strategy (fastest) to store the values in data, not using AppendTo?

Comment: @LeoRon7 the standard method for allocating a buffer when one does not know how much to preallocate, is to allocate it using fixed sizes. (one chunk at a time). Start with say size = n, where is n is some number you decide on. Use Table to allocate it. Then use `[[ ]]` to write to it. When it fills up, you can allocate another list of size n. And so on. If you need all those chunks in memory, you make a linked list of them. And so on. Here is an example of linked list http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node525.html

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html) as a dynamic variable that corresponds to the time elapsed since the start of the evaluation.

```
Dynamic@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Clock[Infinity]}]
```

[image]

Comment: How to solve the "shaking" of the plot? The input line moves up and down... even if I fix the plot dimensions with ImageSize.

Comment: @LeoRon7 Try fixing the vertical `PlotRange`.

Comment: I tried to fix the vertical PlotRange values, but there is still a shaking...

Comment: @LeoRon7 I don't know how to make it go away if you want to keep the animation running *within Mathematica*.